# Electron and TypeScript source code protection

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I want to build an Electron app. I will use TypeScript + React. What I want to know is, Do I have to include `*.ts(x)` files with electron final product? I read about `asar`. Does `asar` also includes TS files or just compile them into JS and exclude it.

And if possible and not by default how can I keep my TS files private but just provide JS along with electron (inside)? tl;dr: How do I make sure my `*.ts(x)` files are not included in electron app?